# Adding magento to an existing website

Tags: magento, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I was curious if anyone knows if it is possible to add magento to an existing website. I want the website look the same. The website has products and buttons/links for adding to shopping cart, but it has no shopping cart functionality. Is this possible? If so, where could I read up on this? Any help is greatly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some magento functionality by including the Mage.php file in your normal non-magento website. This would allow you to perform magento operations (such as add to cart, ...)

Example:

```
<?php 
include("location/to/app/Mage.php");
Mage::app();

// Any magento code is possible here :)
?>
```

Comment: Added a small example, if you need more just let me know ;)

Comment: Awesome. I will try this out tonight and let you know.